# Connection Refused Docker Run

Tags: python, docker, logstash, dockerfile

I'm getting a connection refused after building my Docker image and running `docker run -t imageName`

Inside the container my python script is making web requests (external API call) and then communicating over localhost:5000 to a logstash socket.

My dockerfile is really simple:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update -y

RUN apt-get install -y nginx git python-setuptools python-dev

RUN easy_install pip

#Install app dependencies
RUN pip install requests configparser

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 5000

#Add project directory 
ADD . /usr/local/scripts/

#Set default working directory
WORKDIR /usr/local/scripts

CMD ["python", "logs.py"]
```

However, I get a `[ERROR] Connection refused` message when I try to run this. It's not immediately obvious to me what I'm doing wrong here - I believe I'm opening 80 and 5000 to the outside world? Is this incorrect? Thanks.

Comment: I always have to use the`-P srd:dst` flags when using docker to expose the ports... i think expose is if you link it to another docker image with the -L flag ... or use `docker ps` to see the actual port its mapped to

Answer (score 3):

Regarding `EXPOSE`:

Each container you run has its own network interface. Doing `EXPOSE 5000` tell docker to link a port 5000 *from* container-network-interface to a random port in your host machine (see it with `docker ps`), as long as you tell docker to do it when you `docker run` with `-P`.

Regarding logstash.

If your logstash is installed in your host, or in another container, it means that logstash is not in the "localhost" of the container (remember that each container has its own network interface, each one has its own `localhost`). So you need to point to logstash properly.

How?

*Method 1:*

Don't give container its own iterface, so it has the same `localhost` as your machine:

```
docker run --net=host ...
```

---

*Method 2:*

If you are using docker-compose, use the docker network linking. i.e:

```
services:
  py_app:
    ...
    links:
      - logstash
  logstash:
     image: .../logstash..
```

So point as this: `logstash:5000` (docker will resolve that name to the internal IP corresponding to `logstash`)

---

*Method 3:*

If logstash listen in your `localhost:5000` (from your host), you can point to it as this: `172.17.0.1:5000` from inside your container (the `172.17.0.1` is the `host` fixed IP, but this option is less elegant, arguably)

Comment: Thanks for this! I can definitely rework the logstash piece. What's interesting is my code first makes an API request (in the python script) to pull some JSON and then pumps it to logstash over a socket. Could the `connection refused` be the container trying to reach the internet to make this API call? I'm assuming it would also get blocked trying to reach logstash, but the API call is first. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Then you should see such connection refuse as a python exception, showing you the line of code of the error. What is the complete error message?

Comment: When using docker-platform module from puppet forge, note that $net argument of class docker::run defaults to 'bridge'. Setting it to 'host' (method 1 above) solved similar problems I had following the tutorial at  https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/